# Deleting duplicates row for a column using multiple table relation in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am containing database for a shop who sells pets like dog, cat etc, for my project.

I have table name Animal , where I have details of animal name , which can be discovery in another table 
name ANIMAL_DISCOVERY about the type ,whether its a DOG or cat or ETC.

For each dscvr type, I have 4 or 5 category like Expensive, more Expensive, cheap,affordable. This category I am maintaining in a different table name Animal_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY.

and the last table I have is the Animal_DISCOVERY_RULES that a animal should follow as his/her behaviour.

```
ANIMAL - ANIMAL_NAME,ANIMAL_ID

ANIMAL_DISCOVERY - ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_GROUP, ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID

ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY - ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID,ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT

ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES - ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID,ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID,ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID,ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_TEXT
```

Now Here is my issues, I have a lot of data in ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES. For Each Animal type and its category I have duplicates rules in ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES  table, which I want to delete preserving only one.

Please help me on writing a query which can perform this action.

Below is the query and result

```
select appl.ANIMAL_NAME,cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,count(ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_TEXT) AS RULE_COUNT from ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES rul INNER JOIN
    ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY cate ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID=cate .ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID INNER JOIN
    ANIMAL_DISCOVERY grp ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID=grp.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID INNER JOIN
    ANIMAL appl ON grp.ANIMAL_ID= appl.ANIMAL_ID
    group by cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,appl.ANIMAL_NAME

Animal Name    Category Rules
A1             Dog      Do not use hot water for bath
A1             Cat      Do not use hot water for bath
A1             Dog      Do not use hot water for bath
C1             Dog      Give regular injection
C1             Parrot   Do not give more then 2 chilli a day
```

What I want is that for animal name A1 , for the category Dog there is repeated rules. I want to delete all these types of duplicate rules for all animal name group by its category.

Hope its more clear.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlserver? These are not the same thing. Also, you question is very unclear.

Comment: Some sample data and showing the result after would be nice

Comment: @SeanLange.. its sql server

Comment: Please show some sample data, expected output, and what you have tried already.  Thanks.

Comment: @t_m.. this is my query to select ... select appl.ANIMAL_NAME,cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,count(ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_TEXT) AS RULE_COUNT from ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES rul INNER JOIN
 ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY cate ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID=cate .ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID INNER JOIN
 ANIMAL_DISCOVERY grp ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID=grp.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID INNER JOIN
 ANIMAL appl ON grp.ANIMAL_ID= appl.ANIMAL_ID
 group by cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,appl.ANIMAL_NAME

Comment: @SumitTiwari.. Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @t_m Updates the query and result

Comment: Your question is still extremely vague. The best anybody can do from what you provided so far is guess. I think you need to create ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: (my assumption is your Animal_Discover_Rules_id is the pk and you don't care which rows you keep.)

```
 ;With DistinctDiscoveryRule AS
 (   
 SELECT appl.ANIMAL_NAME
 ,cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,
 min(​ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID) AS ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID 
 from ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES rul INNER JOIN 
 ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY cate ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID=cate .ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_ID INNER JOIN 
 ANIMAL_DISCOVERY grp ON rul.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID=grp.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_ID INNER JOIN ANIMAL appl ON grp.ANIMAL_ID= appl.ANIMAL_ID 
 group by cate.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_CATEGORY_TEXT,appl.ANIMAL_NAME

 )
 Delete adr
 FROM   ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES adr LEFT OUTER JOIN
        DistinctDiscoveryRule d on adr.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID = d.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID
 WHERE d.ANIMAL_DISCOVERY_RULES_ID IS NULL
```